# Why (MouseUp mouseDown) are not working on mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, browser

my code takes a mouse position. 
Mobile browser supports html5. but cannot use MouseUp mouseDown
how can i fix it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

  <body style="background-color:3F6E6F;">
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1200" height="1000" onmousedown="mouseDown()" onmouseup="mouseUp()"></canvas>
  <p id="demo"></p>


  <script>
    var depx = 0;
    var depy = 0;
    var flag = 0;

    function writeMessage(canvas, message) {
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      context.font = '18pt Calibri';
      context.fillStyle = 'black';
      context.fillText(message, 10, 25);
    }


    function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
      var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      return {
        x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
        y: evt.clientY - rect.top
      };
    }


    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


    function mouseDown() {
      canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", myFunction);
    }




    function myFunction(evt) {
      var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
      if (flag == 0) {
        depx = mousePos.x;
        depy = mousePos.y;
      }
      flag = 1;


      var message = 'Mouse position: ' + mousePos.x + ',' + mousePos.y + ' abs position ' + (mousePos.x - depx) + ',' + (mousePos.y - depy);
      writeMessage(canvas, message);
    }

    function mouseUp() {
      flag = 0;
      canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", myFunction);
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the Html and Css code, please have a look and help me with some changes if you find any that would help.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144370/using-mousedown-event-on-mobile-without-jquery-mobile) is what you should use for mobile.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because touch events are not mouse events. If you add a mouse, you could get mouse events.

For touch events, you need to use

```
pointerup
pointerdown
```

events/eventlistener. Read more about [pointerup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pointerup) and [pointerdown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pointerdown).

Usage: Add `addEventListener` for pointer as well.

```
document.getElementById('elem1').addEventListener('pointerdown', methodForPointerDown, false);
document.getElementById('elem1').addEventListener('pointerup', methodForPointerUp, false);
```

Answer (score 5):

There is an alternative for MouseUp and mouseDown for mobile browsers sice they dont use a mouse.

You can use **`touchstart`** and **`touchend`** instead of them in your case for a mobile browser.

[There is a link here for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887541/touch-screen-and-javascript-dom-mousedown-event)

Here is another set of event listeners for mobile devices.

[Pointer Events](https://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/)

Here is an example how you detect the pointer device type with pointer event listeners

**Detecting the type of input from a user**

```
window.addEventListener("pointerdown", detectInputType, false);

function detectInputType(event) {
    switch(event.pointerType) {
        case "mouse":
            /* mouse input detected */
            break;
        case "pen":
            /* pen/stylus input detected */
            break;
        case "touch":
            /* touch input detected */
            break;
        default:
            /* pointerType is empty (could not be detected)
            or UA-specific custom type */
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you..

Comment: Just refer the pointer Events link.. it shows how to detect the pointer device and then go accordingly...